# NGINX force SSL for all but health check file?

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb

I have a Rails app with an NGINX reverse proxy behind an AWS ELB. I am terminating SSL on the ELB and I have NGINX configured to force any attempt at HTTP to rewrite as HTTPS. This setup works fine, but I'm also serving the site through ECS, and since the ELB health check is on HTTP port 80, when it gets the redirect and returns 301, the ELB health check fails and the instance is deregistered.

How do I set up NGINX to send all but the health check file through HTTPS?

Here is my server block from nginx.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        root /var/www/html;

        location ~ ^elbcheck\.html$ {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass http://rails_app;
          break;
        }

        location / {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_next_upstream error;

          if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
          }

          try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|svg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|woff|woff2|map)$ {
            proxy_cache APP;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 5m;
            proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control";
            expires 1d;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

            proxy_pass http://rails_app;
        }

        location @proxy {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

            proxy_pass  http://rails_app;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and found this answer somewhere on the internet (don't have the source anymore, it was a while ago)

```
server {
    listen 80;

    set $redirect_to_https 0;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        set $redirect_to_https 1;
    }

    if ($request_uri = '/status') {
        set $redirect_to_https 0;
    }

    if ($redirect_to_https = 1) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I would only add access_log off; to avoid logging every call from your load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple answer that worked great at [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/518224). Here is what @ceejayoz suggested there:

> ```
> server {
>   location /elb-status {
>     access_log off;
>     return 200;
>   }
> }
> ```

Seems to be working--ECS hasn't terminated my service due to failed health checks anymore.

Comment: the problem with this approach is that nginx will respond to the health check, not the rails app, so it bypasses one of the objectives of the health check: to remove unhealthy instances where the Rails server is not responding. You may have a situation where nginx responds but the rails app doesn't and your users will still be redirected to this faulty instance.